# Undoing a staged delete on remote repo

Tags: git

Definitely new to git, I un-intendedly deleted a couple of files.  They seem to be in a oddish stage on the repo.  After I do a clone, the status output is

> Changes to be committed:

> (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

> deleted:    Makefile

> deleted:    master.cpp

I can reset locally and get the files back, but how to I push the reset so the files aren't deleted?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I can reset locally and get the files back, but how to I push the reset so the files aren't deleted?

You don't need to. Do the reset as the status message advises you, and stop. There is no need to push anything. The "on remote repo" in your title is a red herring. You haven't committed the deletion, and you haven't pushed the deletion, so once you reset, you'll be back to a clean slate with nothing to do.

Just a further short explanation of what you are seeing. The way git works is that everything you do happens in three steps:

1. Work in the "working tree" (edit, make a new file, delete a file, whatever).
2. Stage that work or any portion of it. This puts information about your work into the "index".
3. Commit. Whatever the "index" says at that moment, that becomes the new commit.

(There is also 4, push. But the only thing you can push is a commit, so if there is no commit there is no push.)

So, you did 1 and 2: you deleted some files, and then you staged that deletion so that "index" knows about it. But you did not do 3. Excellent. So all you have to do is say to the "index" and the "working tree": hey, you know those deletions? Forget about it.

And that is exactly what reset locally will do.